# What does the from content of this query mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning SQL now, I would like to know what is meant within the from, what is contained before and after the dot.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM apler.W_WORKED_INVOICES wwi
```

What does `apler` stand for?

The `W_WORKED_INVOICES` is the table, correct?

Comment: apler is the schema name. (Typically the owner/creator of the table.) Yes, W_WORKED_INVOICES  is the table name.

Comment: apler is the schema name and wwi is just an alias, you can say wwi.* while selecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*appler* is database schema. Schema is defined in the Oracle documentation as a collection of logical data structures or schema objects.
*W_WORKED_INVOICES* is a table  created in the *appler* schema

Comment: And `wii` is a nickname given to this table, or, alias.